# Func<T, bool> on Any() IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core, predicate, npgsql

i try to query (linq to entities EF Core) a navigation properties collection, so i use any() like this :

```
var query = context.MyTable.Where(x => x.mycollectionproperties.Any(p => p.myprop == myvar );
```

It's work perfectly but now i want to construct the predicate and not defined it directly in the query.
so i do :

```
Func<T, bool> mypredicate = (p => p.myprop == myvar);
var query = context.MyTable.Where(x => x.mycollectionproperties.Any(mypredicate);
```

*(I have replace T by my entity name)*

but this generate an error : Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.

How can i construct my predicate to use it on Any() collection ?
Thank's

Comment: Not sure how you get that error, but you should be using expressions. Instead of `Func<>` use this: `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`

Comment: Thank's @DavidG but when you use Any() on collection it wants `Func<T, bool>` and not an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. So i'm a bit confused

Comment: what ef core version are you using? there is a bug in old versions with `Any()`: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8019

Comment: @ingvar : i use EF core 2.3 with npgsql. I just read the github post and when i use `.AsQueryable()`just before `Any()` the query is excuting. But the generated sql query is different because of the asqueryable and it's very slow and not efficient. So i still got my problem :cannot use predicate  with Any() function on IEnumerable. I don't know if it is a bug or if i doing something wrong.

Comment: Looks like it's a bug in ef core. does `var query = context.MyTable.Where(x => x.mycollectionproperties.FirstOrDefault(mypredicate) != null);` works for you btw?

Comment: @ingvar : FirstOrDefault() generate the same error than any().

Answer (score 0):

This line for example:

`var query = context.MyTable.Where(x => x.mycollectionproperties.Any(p => p.myprop == 1));`

When compiled will be compiled to something like this:

```
var xParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Entity1), "x");

var pParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Entity2), "p");

var anyMethod =
    typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethods()
        .Single(x => x.Name == "Any" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2)
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Entity2));

var anyCondition = Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity2, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(
            pParameter,
            typeof(Entity2).GetProperty("myprop").GetMethod),
        Expression.Constant(1, typeof(int))),
    pParameter);

var query = context.MyTable.Where(
    Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity1, bool>>(
        Expression.Call(
            null,
            anyMethod,
            new Expression[] {
                Expression.Property(
                    xParameter,
                    typeof(Entity1).GetProperty("mycollectionproperties").GetMethod),
                anyCondition
            }),
        xParameter));
```

This is called an expression tree. See this reference for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/

Although the `Any` method takes a `Func`, when constructing the expression tree, notice that an expression (`Expression<Func<Entity2, bool>>`) is given to the `Any` method.

There doesn't seem to be a way from C# to give the `Any` method an expression instead of a `Func` even if the whole thing is an expression tree (I mean in a parameterized way like you want to achieve).

The most obvious way to achieve what you want is to use the code from this post and replace the `anyCondition` variable with whatever expression you want to use for the condition inside `Any`.

Another way is to construct part of the expression tree "normally" and pass `null` to the `Any` method and then use an expression visitor to replace the `null` with your expression. Here is how such visitor would look like:

```
public class AnyMethodArgumentReplacingVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression expression;

    public AnyMethodArgumentReplacingVisitor(Expression expression)
    {
        this.expression = expression;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Method.Name == "Any")
        {
            return Expression.Call(node.Object, node.Method, node.Arguments[0], expression);
        }

        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
}
```

Here is how you would use it:

```
Expression<Func<Entity2, bool>> predicate =
    a => a.myprop == 2;

Expression<Func<Entity1, bool>> expression =
    b => b.mycollectionproperties.Any(null);

var expression2 =
    (Expression<Func<Entity1, bool>>)
        new AnyMethodArgumentReplacingVisitor(predicate).Visit(expression);
```

Please note that such visitor would replace the call to any `Any` method. It also assumes that only the overload of `Any` that takes a predicate is used. There is another overload of `Any` that does not take a predicate. If you need to use that, you need to adjust the code.

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me your problem is in your definition of

```
Func<T, bool> mypredicate = (p => p.myprop == myvar);
```

You should not use **T**, you should use the type of **mycollectionproperties**

Assuming the property **mycollectionproperties** is defined as something like this

```
....
public IQueryable<YourType> mycollectionproperties { get; set; }
....
```

Then you should declare **mypredicate** as

```
Func<YourType, bool> mypredicate = (p => p.myprop == myvar);
```

You can see a working sample on [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UNFS5m)

Comment: I have already change T by my type, i just wrote T for the example, but the problem still there,

Comment: yes i look at your code (thank's) and i do exactly the same method but it doesn't work at the compilation time for me. But i use it with EF core 2.1 with npgsql and it maybe different than linq on list<T> or it's a bug, i don't know...